# How to get data from text table string in C# more reliably and quickly

Tags: c#, string, text, clipboard

I'm copying some data from SAP GUI screen to clipboard. It looks like below when I paste it on Notepad or any text editor.

[image: SAP GUI data]

I want only 3 fields[Created by, PO date, Document] from the clipboard text table string.

Currently I'm managing to read data as below.

```
public class DocData
{
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string PODate { get; set; }
    public string Document { get; set; }
}

private void GetDocumentData()
{
  var clipboardData = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Text);
  List<DocData> docDataList = new List<DocData>();
  for (int separatorCounter = 20; separatorCounter < clipboardData.Count(); separatorCounter = separatorCounter + 13)
  {
   DocData docData = new DocData();
   int index = GetNthIndex(clipboardData, '|', separatorCounter);
   if (index != -1)
   {
    var dataString = clipboardData.Substring(index + 1);
    var sepIndex = dataString.IndexOf('|');
    if (sepIndex != -1)
    {
     docData.CreatedBy = dataString.Substring(0, sepIndex).Trim();
    }
   }
   index = GetNthIndex(clipboardData, '|', separatorCounter + 2);
   if (index != -1)
   {
    var dataString = clipboardData.Substring(index + 1);
    var sepIndex = dataString.IndexOf('|');
    if (sepIndex != -1)
    {
     docData.PODate = dataString.Substring(0, sepIndex).Trim();
    }
   }
   index = GetNthIndex(clipboardData, '|', separatorCounter + 4);
   if (index != -1)
   {
    var dataString = clipboardData.Substring(index + 1);
    var sepIndex = dataString.IndexOf('|');
    if (sepIndex != -1)
    {
     docData.Document = dataString.Substring(0, sepIndex).Trim();
    }
   }
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(docData.Document))
   {
    docDataList.Add(docData);
   }
  }
 }
```

Can anyone suggest better way to do this without manipulating string too much.

Comment: How about `Split`

Comment: And what about using subroutines instead of copy/paste?

Comment: It looks like fixed format data, you could just get the values from specific places in the string

Comment: String.Split (which will give you an array for every line)  and .Trim (to clear up the whitespace in individual fields) should work well to do the majority of the heavy lifting for you!

Comment: to be a bit clearer: String.Split on the clipboard text with a CR or CRLF as seperator (depending on your file line terminators) will give you individual lines, then String.Split on these lines with "|"  (which will give you an array for every line)  and .Trim (to clear up the whitespace in individual fields).

Comment: @MohitShrivastava Split works perfect. Thanks a lot for guidance.

Comment: Thanks @kpollock

Comment: you are welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach to your problem. This example first splits your text by lines, then uses header to find locations of data you need, and then iterates through lines and gets data.

Haven't tested it (I could if you pasted text instead of that screenshot :)), but it should work. Take a look at comments in code for explanation.

If you have additional questions, feel free to ask.

EDIT: Added missing method

```
//result list
List<DocData> docDataList = new List<DocData>();

//get clipboard data
string clipboardData = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Text);

//split it to array of lines using Environment.NewLine (\r\n);
string[] reportLines = clipboardData.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);

if (reportLines.Length < 4) //just an example of checking if there's enough lines
    throw new Exception("wrong number of lines");

//get correct indexes by reading header (positioned on third line, index 2) - in case order changes
int createdIndex = GetColumnIndex(reportLines[2], "Created by");
int PODateIndex = GetColumnIndex(reportLines[2], "PO Date");
int documentIndex = GetColumnIndex(reportLines[2], "Document");

//when you have indexes, loop through remaining lines, starting at fifth (index 4) and get data from that "columns"
for (int i = 4; i<reportLines.Length; i++)
{
    //now split current line by pipes
    string[] lineData = reportLines[i].Split('|');
    //create instance of your class and add data from specific indexes
    DocData docData = new DocData()
    {
        CreatedBy = lineData[createdIndex].Trim(), //also, trim ending spaces,
        PODate = lineData[PODateIndex].Trim(),
        Document = lineData[documentIndex].Trim()
    };
    docDataList.Add(docData);
}

public int GetColumnIndex(string headerLine, string columnName)
{
    List<string> headerNames = headerLine.Split('|').ToList(); //split header columns using pipe |.

    //get index of column by trimming and searching throught header column names
    return headerNames.IndexOf(headerNames.FirstOrDefault(h => h.Trim().Equals(columnName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)));

}
```

Comment: Helpful. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: @a_programmer glad I could help. I saw that noone is writing an answer (although the comments were good) and I didn't know your level od knowledge so I took a little time to write an example

Comment: I appreciate your level of understanding the people. I'm not an expert but trying to be. I was working my own to get data with 'string.Split()' and your code also guided me to make my code perfect and working.